# How do I do merge of two tables where two dates are closest?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables A and B like the following. I would like to merge them by Items but only in the place where the return date is after the order date and the return date is closest to the corresponding order date for the item. The resulted table is C below. Could you please help to see how I can realize this merge in SQL code?

The return dates are not necessary to be in the same year as the order date, but it should be assigned to the closest order date given that the return date is after the order date. For example, for item 1, return date 9/15/2009 is closest to 8/14/2009 among the three order dates for item 1, so it is assigned to 8/14/2009. Again for item 1, return date 9/15/2011 is after all the three order dates for item 1, but it is closest to 8/16/2011, so it is assigned to 8/16/2011.

Thanks a lot!

Table A:

```
Items    Order_Date
1        8/14/2009
1        8/15/2010
1        8/16/2011
2        9/10/2009
2        9/8/2010
2        9/12/2011
```

Table B:

```
Items    Return_Date
1        9/15/2009
1        9/15/2011
2        10/15/2010
2        11/15/2011
```

Final results table C:

```
Items        Order_Date    Return_Date
1            8/14/2009     9/15/2009
1            8/15/2010     NULL
1            8/16/2011     9/15/2011
2            9/10/2009     NULL
2            9/8/2010      10/15/2010
2            9/12/2011     11/15/2011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used an [`APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634) here also. It seems to match your sample data:

(Sample data at end of answer)

```
;with MatchedOrders as (
    select
        a.Items,a.Order_Date, b.Return_Date 
    from
        @TableB b
            cross apply
        (select top 1 * from @TableA a
             where a.Items = b.Items and a.Order_Date < b.Return_Date
             order by a.Order_Date desc) a
)
select
    a.Items,
    a.Order_Date,
    mo.Return_Date
from
    @TableA a
        left join
    MatchedOrders mo
        on
            a.Items = mo.Items and a.Order_Date = mo.Order_Date
```

Result:

```
Items       Order_Date                  Return_Date
----------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
1           2009-08-14 00:00:00.0000000 2009-09-15 00:00:00.0000000
1           2010-08-15 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
1           2011-08-16 00:00:00.0000000 2011-09-15 00:00:00.0000000
2           2009-09-10 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
2           2010-09-08 00:00:00.0000000 2010-10-15 00:00:00.0000000
2           2011-09-12 00:00:00.0000000 2011-11-15 00:00:00.0000000
```

---

Sample data:

```
declare @TableA table (Items int not null,Order_Date datetime2 not null)
insert into @TableA(Items,Order_Date) values
(1,'20090814'),
(1,'20100815'),
(1,'20110816'),
(2,'20090910'),
(2,'20100908'),
(2,'20110912')

declare @TableB table (Items int not null,Return_Date datetime2 not null)
insert into @TableB(Items,Return_Date) values
(1,'20090915'),
(1,'20110915'),
(2,'20101015'),
(2,'20111115')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think OUTER APPLY is what you need.  Have you tried something like this (SQLServer):

```
Select A.ItemID, A.OrderDate, [ReturnDates].ReturnDate
from Orders A
    OUTER APPLY (
        select Min(ReturnDate) as ReturnDate 
        From [Returns] b 
        where b.ReturnDate >= A.OrderDate AND b.ItemID = A.ItemID
        ) as ReturnDates
```

Comment: Thanks RyanD, but the result is not exact the same as I posted where there are "NULL"s.

Comment: PSN Order_Date opt_out_date
1 8/14/2009 9/15/2009
1 8/15/2010 9/15/2011
1 8/16/2011 9/15/2011
2 9/10/2009 10/15/2010
2 9/8/2010 10/15/2010
2 9/12/2011 11/15/2011

Comment: Lin, I don't see how you got the results in table C from the criteria that you explained.  Perhaps you need to clarify.  Are the return dates supposed to be in teh same year?

Comment: Hi Jim, sorry if I didn't illustrate the logic well. No, the return dates are not supposed to be in the same year as the order date, but it should be assigned to the closest order date. For example, item 1, return date 9/15/2009 is closest to 8/14/2009 among the three order dates for item 1, so it is assigned to 8/14/2009. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select  ord.Items,ord.Order_Date,l.Return_Date  from orders ord
left join 
(
select * from (
select *,row_number() over (partition by return_date order by diff asc) as rn from (

select b.Items,b.Order_Date,a.Return_Date,a.diff  from 

(select o.Items,o.Order_Date,r.Return_Date,DATEDIFF(dd,o.Order_Date,r.Return_Date) diff  from orders o join ord_ret r
on o.Items = r.Items) a inner join 

(select a.Items,a.Order_Date,MIN(abs(a.diff)) as diff
from (
select o.Items,o.Order_Date,r.Return_Date,DATEDIFF(dd,o.Order_Date,r.Return_Date) diff  from orders o join ord_ret r
on o.Items = r.Items ) a
group by a.Items,a.Order_Date) b

on a.Items = b.Items and a.diff = b.diff  and a.Return_Date > b.Order_Date ) a) final
where rn<> 2) l

on ord.Items = l.Items and ord.Order_Date = l.Order_Date
```